# What is a good column type to use for storing a list of ids in mysq?

Tags: mysql, list

What is a good column type to use to store a list of ids.

for example i want to store 10,50,100,65456,9,102346,546465

What is the best way to store such a list?

Thanks

Comment: Varchar. That's a poor way to store your data.

Comment: @JohnConde: Did you mean to say "Not varchar; it would be a poor way to store such data."? Your actual phrasing comes across (to me) as the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use another table to store that data. If you're looking to store your data as

```
ID   idlist
1    10,50,100,65456,9,102346,546465
```

create an additional table and save yourself headaches

```
ID newid
1  10
1  500
1  100
1  65456
1  9
1  102346
1  546465
```

Comment: so your saying storing the data into 2 different tables is better storing a list of the ids?

Answer (score 0):

Dont save it as a csv as searching is slow. I usually keep a mapping table like

```
| parent_id | linked_id | status
```

with parent_id, linked_id as primary/unique key. This makes all your queries fast.

If you stick with csv itself, you can varchar(100) and thereafter `find_in_set` to seacrh for a particular id in the list(no index  will be used)

Like

Schools

```
School_id | name
```

Subjects

```
Subject_id | name
```

Link_table

```
School_id | Subject_id | Status
```